# Image map not functioning correctly

Tags: html, imagemap

Why my image map not working?
No matter where I click on the image map, it does not take me to the next page?

```
<img id="maptreebg" alt="" src="/handheld/images/mainbody/body_interactive_image_default.png" usemap="#maptree" />
<map id="maptree"> 
    <area id="ar1" shape="poly" coords="3,390,13,381,66,371,113,351,172,313,193,290,217,273,242,259,297,238,344,222,394,213,461,206,521,202,588,205,638,208,694,221,751,249,800,289,835,340,852,397,849,435,815,494,781,526,767,543,728,566,670,586,614,593,521,597,467,590,386,585,309,565,276,554,253,542,228,537,174,503,113,464,76,438,36,416,6,398,4,394" alt="Love"  href="/handheld/terms.htm" />
    <area id="ar2" shape="poly" coords="1990,389,1967,376,1929,373,1879,351,1846,334,1814,308,1786,279,1705,243,1636,220,1549,210,1475,203,1399,204,1331,212,1267,232,1213,268,1179,303,1155,336,1138,390,1138,419,1153,462,1191,510,1226,545,1305,581,1368,593,1448,597,1540,587,1610,586,1674,566,1737,545,1775,530,1841,487,1913,440,1949,416,1968,414,1991,392" alt="Family"  href="/handheld/terms.htm" />
    <area id="ar3" shape="poly" coords="0,849,32,835,73,827,123,806,156,779,188,749,227,723,292,699,358,676,426,667,517,662,609,664,654,671,727,692,770,721,807,755,834,796,850,842,852,880,845,906,814,952,776,993,736,1017,689,1038,635,1051,573,1054,494,1053,435,1045,384,1043,328,1030,272,1013,256,1003,218,993,186,968,149,944,118,924,92,906,66,890,47,878,22,867" alt="Friend" href="/handheld/terms.htm" />
    <area id="ar4" shape="poly" coords="1987,848,1972,837,1919,826,1868,805,1812,760,1773,728,1668,684,1585,669,1492,661,1385,662,1301,675,1225,712,1178,760,1158,794,1137,853,1143,896,1180,959,1224,1000,1294,1039,1365,1050,1470,1055,1552,1045,1615,1040,1677,1023,1757,996,1815,963,1876,925,1924,890,1969,866,1991,848,1985,850" alt="Colleaque" href="/handheld/terms.htm" />
    <area id="ar5" shape="poly" coords="0,1305,16,1295,55,1290,109,1266,139,1253,172,1226,208,1193,253,1171,315,1145,388,1128,480,1117,582,1119,644,1124,701,1141,758,1168,808,1211,835,1257,853,1310,847,1359,796,1428,750,1468,713,1487,645,1509,556,1509,493,1509,432,1505,368,1497,317,1482,265,1467,231,1453,187,1429,73,1352,43,1335,21,1326,6,1312" alt="Business" href="/handheld/terms.htm" />
    <area id="ar6" shape="poly" coords="1987,1302,1960,1293,1914,1281,1865,1262,1815,1222,1777,1191,1692,1154,1614,1130,1520,1121,1409,1117,1331,1126,1280,1145,1216,1178,1177,1225,1159,1251,1140,1302,1138,1323,1145,1358,1174,1409,1222,1456,1263,1481,1330,1503,1373,1510,1463,1512,1539,1503,1606,1500,1667,1485,1707,1476,1732,1460,1771,1449,1827,1412,1909,1355,1980,1319" alt="Educator/Learner" href="/handheld/terms.htm" />
    <area id="ar7" shape="poly" coords="47,3567,995,3069,1952,3569,1839,3569,1839,3568,1772,3569" alt="Registration"  href="/handheld/terms.htm" />
</map>
```

Answer (score 2):

You'r using the wrong attribute to identify the `<map>`. Try `name` instead of `id`.

> The name attribute gives the map a name so that it can be referenced. The attribute must be present and must have a non-empty value with no space characters. The value of the name attribute must not be a compatibility-caseless match for the value of the name attribute of another map element in the same document. If the id attribute is also specified, both attributes must have the same value.
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map#Attributes

Comment: Ayman: The reason I use ID instead of Name is because I am trying to locate the map object inside my JaveScript using document.getElementById('maptree'). Will using Name works with getElementById?

Comment: No, but you can have both `id` _and_ `name`. Nothing wrong with that. Alternatively, you could use [`getElementsByAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Method/getElementsByAttribute) or [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to reference the map object.

Comment: Either way, the `name` attribute is not optional. You _must_ have it in order for the `<map>` element to work.